# HTML5 Canvas, my arc draw a startline to the center

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

The arc have the following result. Do I have to calculate the start point of the arc myself? jsfiddle link here: [jsfiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/8EDHb/)

[image: Snapshot]

```
canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
context.lineWidth = 1;
//   context.moveTo(49, 49);
context.arc(19, 19, 15, 0, 1 * Math.PI);
context.moveTo(49, 49);
context.arc(49, 49, 15, 0, 1 * Math.PI);

context.stroke();
```

Comment: What do you want your results to look like?

Comment: don't have enough "reputation" to post image. It's in the jsfiddle.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want a full circle?

Comment: I want two same arcs at two different locations. Right now, the second arc has a horizontal line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the path each time:

http://jsfiddle.net/8EDHb/1/

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(19, 19, 15, 0, 1 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
context.moveTo(49, 49);
context.beginPath();
context.arc(49, 49, 15, 0, 1 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete circle you should use `2 * Math.PI`.
You can make javascript calculate the starting position, for a circle with `center (cx,cy)` and `radius r`.

Use `context.arc(cx + r,cy)` and so on
If you have definite values,
Eg. Centre at 100,100 and radius 50 use

```
context.arc(150,100,...)
```